# creating default parameters when making a object using object.create

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to optionally declare `dots: {}` from inside `Object.create`?

As you can see I have tried

1. standard default parameter assignment
2. tried using a nullish coalescing

Neither work.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```js
'use strict'

let Carousel = function(name, dots=true) {
  this.name = name
  this.dots = dots ?? true
}
Carousel.prototype.show = function() {
  console.log(`${this.name} and ${this.dots}`)
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let usps = Object.create(Carousel.prototype, { 
    name: { value: 'element name', writeable: false}
    // dots: { value: true, writeable: false }
  })
  usps.show()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you don't use `new` keyword and instead create object from prototype, but in either case, if you set default value to prototype of your object, you will get dots on it.

```js
let Carousel = function(name, dots) {
  this.name = name
  this.dots = dots
}
Carousel.prototype.show = function() {
  console.log(`${this.name} and ${this.dots}`)
}

Carousel.prototype.dots = true;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let usps = Object.create(Carousel.prototype, { 
    name: { value: 'element name', writeable: false},
  })
  usps.show() // will show that dots equals true
  let usps2 = Object.create(Carousel.prototype, { 
    name: { value: 'element name', writeable: false},
    dots: { value: false, writeable: false }
  });
  usps2.show(); // will show that dots equals false
})
```

It is important, that if you will want to use `new` operator, you will have to modify your constructor, so if there is no dots parameter set, you will not override one with `undefined`:

```js
let Carousel = function (name, dots) {
  this.name = name;
  if (dots !== undefined) {
    this.dots = dots;
  }
};
Carousel.prototype.show = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name} and ${this.dots}`);
};

Carousel.prototype.dots = true;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let usps = new Carousel("element name");
  usps.show();
  let usps2 = new Carousel("element name 2", false);
  usps2.show();
});
```

Comment: thank you @ezhikov your advice is very much appreciated and certainly helped me. FYI I am using `Object.create` to effortlessly stop Monkey Patching.

Comment: @dimButTries Could you elaborate on that? Nothing about using `Object.create()` makes modifying code harder or easier per se.

Comment: @Etheryte hi sure, this is a tip, I picked up from a book called 'Javascript: Functional Programming for Javascript Developers'. Using `object.create` and setting `writable:false`. I cannot edit name from outside its creation. Here is a snippet which I added to JSbin https://jsbin.com/buwatopaji/edit?js,console

Comment: @dimButTries Thanks for explaining, it's been years since I've done anything on this side of Javascript. A good example of how you forget what you don't use. While it isn't identical, you may also consider [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Comment: @dimButTries, instead of calling `Object.create` every time, you can use `Object.defineProperty` in constructor and on prototype with same results. Here is an [example](https://jsbin.com/tololelezu/1/edit?js,console)